Axis2 doesn't see any services when deployed in ear
I have crated simple webservice with axis2 (1.4.1), without aar files, i have just "services.xml" in proper directory (WEB-INF/services/MyService/META-INF). After deploying WAR on Weblogic 8.1 service works without any issues and is visible on /listServices. When I use same WAR as a part of EAR I get next error:

"The service cannot be found for the
  endpoint reference (EPR)"

and /listServices is empty. Other servlets contained in WAR aren't affected and work same way when deployed as WAR or EAR.

Axis requires exploded WAR in EAR. However that won't work with WL 8.1, it throws an exception during deployment. I ended up modifying axis so it extracts war just before it starts searching for services - ugly hack but works flawlessly. 
